# Is it okey to store integer and uuid in one column of type varchar?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

In my app there are anonymous and authenticated users, authenticated users has Long id given by AuthService, anonymous users has uuid to be identified in app. I have a table item which stores items of each user, as below

```
Item
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
| item_id |                user_id                 | quantity |
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
|      1  | '1'                                    |        2 |
|      2  | 'a0eebc99-9c0b-4ef8-bb6d-6bb9bd380a11' |        3 |
|      3  | '2'                                    |        1 |
+---------+----------------------------------------+----------+
```

Is it ok to store Long id and uuid in one column of type varchar?

Answer (score 0):

It is OK in that it is technically possible.

If that is a good design is another question. For one, you are needlessly wasting storage space if you store a UUID as text. This will also affect the size of any index on the column. Also, this way you have no protection against anybody storing `hello` in that column.

In general, it is best to choose the appropriate data type for your data: `timestamp` for timestamps, `uuid` for UUIDs and `bigint` for generated numeric keys.

If this is not a key column but user data (you don't want the value in a join condition), you could use two columns of the appropriate type and a check constraint that makes sure that exactly one of the columns is set.

Comment: I would also question the design decision that the "ID generation" depends on the type of user. I would use the same strategy for both types. The primary key of the `users` table would have to deal with the same "hack".